# She has been being mistreated

Tags: passive-voice, past-perfect

> She is being mistreated. She has been being mistreated for five years.

Is the second sentence grammatically correct? Or should the `being been` be contracted to just `been`? I. e. `She has been mistreated for five years.`

> She was mistreated. She has been mistreated.

If so, how to disambiguate it from the above formation? The original has a progressive connotation, and the one right above is simple.

I came up with the second sentence by converting `was` to `had been` and leaving the `being` as is. That's because that's what I do with sentences such as `She is eating` -> `She has been eating` (I leave the `eating` as is).

Comment: Being should be deleted

Comment: @Avrumi edited the question; how to disambiguate from "She was mistreated." -> "She had been mistreated." then "She was being mistreated." -> "She was ...???" Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "have been being investigated" in the following sentence grammatically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103725/is-have-been-being-investigated-in-the-following-sentence-grammatically-correc)

Answer (score 1):

For the convenience of learners, it is to be remembered , that passive voice has only one verb , i.e. "TO BE". Let us conjugate it like this:He is/ He is being/ He has been/ He has been being/ He was/He was being. . . So on and so forth.

In whatever form the MAIN VERB is in active voice with whatever inflections ('s/-ing/ ed/en/ or internal change) it would invariably be changed to V3 or past participle form. The main verb in passive voice is acted upon, for convenience, better call it an adjective.

- Some one is mistreating her.
- Someone has been mistreating her for five years.

Conversation of these two would give us the first two sentences. However, what you want to mean is essentially yours. The rules are enumerated for your convenience, this much!

Answer (score 0):

Both *Being* and *Been* are verbs for 'to be'. the problem is having two in one sentence. *Has been* means she was mistreated. *Is being* means she is currently being mistreated, that is Now.